# Send reminder email for unattended items in custom list

Tags: sharepoint-designer

how can I set a 72 hour reminder to unattended items in a custom list? I need the reminder to only be sent once.

Hope I find some help here, thanks in advance!

Comment: Does my answer help you? Please let us know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pause your workflow with the action "Pause for duration" in an SharePoint Designer 2010 Workflow.

1. Open your list in SharePoint Designer (fastest way in the ribbon "Edit List")

[image]

2. Then SharePoint Designer will open up. *You might get a security warning.* In there click on "New" in the Workflow section.

[image]

3. Now type in a name for your Workflow, optional a description and select your Platform type. (SharePoint 2010 Workflow or if correctly installed, SharePoint 2013 Workflow). In this case a SharePoint 2010 Workflow is ok.

[image]

4. Now you can type in "pause" and you will automatically get two auto suggested results.

[image]

5. Press "Enter" to see those two and select "Pause for Duartion".

[image]

6. Now finish you workflow with an if clause where to check if your column contains a specific value. In my case, I check if column "Monitored by" is empty.

[image]

7. Then add another action (type in "email") and in there you can specify your email head and body.

Make sure, that the option "Start workflow automatically when an item is created" **is set**:

[image]

Also important to know, the workflow will never start automatically with the system account.

I wrote a guide "How to create your first 2013 SharePoint Desginer Workflow". You can check that out here if you like: https://afrait.com/blog/how-to-create-your-first-2013-workflow-de-en/

After that your list has a new column (the workflow name) and if you create a new item, the workflow will start automatically.

[image]

Hope this will help someone out there. If you need a SharePoint Designer 2013 Workflow guide, let me know.